# Java Client/Server - Implementing a read/receive loop

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I am working on a client/server project for class. I have the server set up so that it is listening for inputs and will relay appropriate message/messages back to the client. For example, client sends input "help" to the server, the server will respond with 5 lines of strings back to the client's console. This is done with the code:

```
while (true) {
        System.out.print('>');
        inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        toServer.write(inputLine + '\n');
        toServer.flush();

        while ((serverInput = fromServer.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(serverInput);
        }
```

So I believe the problem with this is that it is indefinitely waiting for serverInputs at the end. I would like it to go back to reading inputs from the console after all the appropriate messages have been received. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you have control of the server? If you do, you can make a small protocol for that. If you don't you can just analyze the possible responses the server gives, and then control the client based on it. Either way, it is going to be looping *util* a particular condition.

Comment: yes, I wrote the server myself and can edit it. What do you mean by a small protocol? as of now, I just added a number at the top of the text file that contains the messages and i parse the number into an int to for loop the exact number of responses. But as I add more functionality to the program, this will not be efficient.

Comment: I mean you can mark the start/end of server messages by using some character, like `\r\n`, or maybe `null` values, so that you can identified that the server has done sending what is to be sent and is ready to accept more data....

Comment: Adding functionality makes it less efficient, this statement is not true. You can make it more configurable, so that you can easily add/remove components that you don't want. By defining a small protocol, or simply saying, a rule by which your client and server communicates would make your server reliable (that might get you good remarks from your instructor as well).